# Selenium web driver and multillanguage

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I use selenium webdriver +java. When I want to get some data/text by xpath, for example

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tr[1]/td[1]")).getText()
```

If I want to get Russian text it retrives me string full of ?????? symbols, instead of text. With english it works fine. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Probably it's how you run those tests. What is the encoding used?

Comment: By default I use UTF-8 Example: def xml = new MarkupBuilder(new FileWriter(file)); xml.mkp.xmlDeclaration(version: "1.0", encoding: "utf-8");

Comment: Have you tried using "ISO-8859-1"?

Comment: I've found that it comes before file saving. I dont know how to change encoding for findElement().getText() function

Comment: Are you running your tests through TestNG, JUnit or something similar? I'm suspecting you need to change the encoding when you start running them. I found similar problems when i ran mine using UTF-8.

Comment: I am having same problem... I getText() returns ???? when reading text where the language is russian or korean or chinese. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can change encoding after element.getTex()

example

```
String tmp = elem.getText();
String utfString = new String(tmp.getBytes(Charset.forName("utf-8")));
```

I use java.nio.Charset to set charset;

Hope it's help you.