# WebElement.getText() function and utf8

Tags: encoding, utf-8, selenium-webdriver

May i assume that for every web page the `WebElement.getText()` function does return utf8 Strings, or can it have other encodings?

If there could be other encodings, how can i identify it and convert it to utf8?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=288

Answer (score 1):

I don't know no one good way(maybe if you like reflection, you can hack and rewrite) to do getText() return needed encoding.
But in this 
[Selenium web driver and multillanguage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913972/selenium-web-driver-and-multillanguage/24449050#24449050) 
I wrote some way to encode String.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. According to the [API](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html), `getText()` returns a `String`. You will have to find the encoding of that from the page headers.